# Predicting the Y variable in a Neural Network gives the same number

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I want to use a neural network with variable X which 50 rows and 5 columns and a variable Y which has 5 different values (categories).

Below is the code that uses softmax because there are 5 classes but the predicted values are always the same number.

As shown below, the normalization has been done on the `X` and `Y` variables.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X).reshape((50,5))
X
```

which gives:

```
array([[ 0.29488391,  0.56011949, -0.46154113, -0.16126706,  0.29488391],
       [-3.39116499, -2.41923951,  1.42589534, -2.24213229,  0.29488391],
       [ 0.29488391,  0.56011949, -0.33571203, -0.94159152, -1.54814054],
       [-3.39116499, -2.41923951,  0.67092075,  0.03381406,  0.29488391],...])
```

and for `Y`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
y = ohe.fit_transform(y).toarray()
y
```

which gives:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],...])
```

and then the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=64)
```

and then the prediction

```
 y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
 pred = list()
 for i in range(len(y_pred):
    pred.append(np.argmax(y_pred[i]))
 test = list()
 for i in range(len(y_test):
    test.append(np.argmax(y_test[i]))
 pred
```

which gives

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

and

```
y_pred
```

which gives

```
 array([[0.07307784, 0.06410044, 0.0949591 , 0.29170573, 0.47615686],
       [0.07307784, 0.06410044, 0.0949591 , 0.29170573, 0.47615686],
       [0.07307784, 0.06410044, 0.0949591 , 0.29170573, 0.47615686],
       [0.07307784, 0.06410044, 0.0949591 , 0.29170573, 0.47615686],
       [0.1443704 , 0.12886432, 0.1797213 , 0.22652027, 0.32052374],
       [0.18675748, 0.18065727, 0.1806546 , 0.202152  , 0.24977861],
       [0.07307784, 0.06410044, 0.0949591 , 0.29170573, 0.47615686],...])
```

Using the `y_pred = model.predict(X_train)` and printing the `y_pred` then returns:

```
array([[1.39623194e-06, 9.69740995e-06, 3.63348372e-05, 1.66217107e-02,
        9.83330905e-01],
       [1.39623194e-06, 9.69740995e-06, 3.63348372e-05, 1.66217107e-02,
        9.83330905e-01],
       [1.00677039e-06, 7.87629324e-06, 2.85332426e-05, 1.69713758e-02,
        9.82991219e-01],
       [1.39623194e-06, 9.69740995e-06, 3.63348372e-05, 1.66217107e-02,
        9.83330905e-01],
       [3.98923963e-01, 1.06269494e-01, 1.76579416e-01, 1.83922082e-01,
        1.34305030e-01],...])
```

Comment: Did you apply the scaling on your test data too?

Comment: Yes, first I did the scaling and then I separated the data between train/test

Comment: How does your `y_pred` look? Can you include it in the question?

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: Seems like it's working fine. Maybe your input data is imbalanecd or you have not trained for enough epochs or using enough data. How do the prediction look for your training data?

Comment: How can I check the prediction for the training data? Can you provide the relevant code?

Comment: Instead of `y_pred = model.predict(X_test)` just use `y_pred = model.predict(X_train)`

Comment: I updated the question with the results of y_pred after the change you requested.

Comment: The output is almost the same (around `[0.   0.   0.   0.02 0.98]` for those rows), maybe it's not learning enough as a I said or you just provided rows for the same class. Try to plot a confusion matrix maybe or check the plot of your training and validation loss

Comment: the problem is that in the dataset there is mostly the number `5`, and very few `4`s. How does it show so many 4s here?

Comment: Python indexes start from 0. `4` is the fifth position, and you're using `argmax` which returns and index

Comment: good point, but why does it return an index and not the actual values?

Comment: What do you mean? You're using `np.argmax`. If you want the original value just use `np.max`

Comment: if I use np.max there is an error when trying to find the accuracy `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'`

Comment: Look, I don't think your code is wrong, you're just using a small sample of data I think. Maybe the labeling is right (I don't know since you didn't show the actual labels)